# How to use external file comparer in MS TFS

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, diff

I don't like ms diff that integrated into Visual Studio 2008 TFS Edition. Is it possible to change this file comparer to external one ([Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), for example)?

Comment: Questions about how to configure and use software development tools are off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It does indeed look like it is possible (link to Beyond Compare makers site outlining how)](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php)

Here are the steps from that link that are specific to Beyond Compare and TFS:

**Diff**

1. In Visual Studio Choose Options from the Tools menu.
2. Expand Source Control in the treeview.
3. Click Visual Studio Team Foundation Server in the treeview.
4. Click the Configure User Tools button.
5. Click the Add button.
6. Enter ".*" in the Extension edit.
7. Choose Compare in the Operation combobox.
8. Enter the path to BComp.exe in the Command edit.
9. In the Arguments edit, use: %1 %2 /title1=%6 /title2=%7

**3-way Merge (v3 Pro)**

1. Follow steps 1-6 above.
2. Choose Merge in the Operation combobox.
3. Enter the path to BComp.exe in the Command edit.
4. In the Arguments edit, use:
   %1 %2 %3 %4 /title1=%6 /title2=%7 /title3=%8 /title4=%9

**2-way Merge (v3 Std, v2)**

Use the same steps as the 3-way merge above, but use the command line:
%1 %2 /savetarget=%4 /title1=%6 /title2=%7